# SSRS parameter one label but multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a query that has classify codes: if 'PC' it returns 'Compatible, if Null then it returns Unclassified, if everything else returns 'Not-Compatible'.  The alias column is "Classification".

```
> SELECT   CASE WHEN class.code IS NULL THEN 'Unclassified'
> WHEN class.Code = 'PC' THEN 'Compatible' ELSE 'Not-Compatible'
> END Classification,  FROM classification class
```

Now I want to set this Classification as a parameter in my SSRS report.

```
WHERE class.Code LIKE @Classification
```

Then in my @Classification parameter[image: Parameter Set up]

So, in my report, user is prompted choose a classification, how do I get user to choose "Everything Else" that returns "Unclassified"?  I can't use the alias column name "Classification" to get value.  If there a way to set multiple values into the label "Unclassified"?

Comment: I don't quite understand but.... your parameter should filter on the _result_ of the case statement which apparently can only be one of three values: Unclassified, Compatible, Not-Compatible. So that's all that should be listed in your _Value_ column, plus the wildcard value (%)

Answer (score 1):

You can build this logic into your WHERE clause. First change the value of Non-Compatible to "NC". Then you could do something like this:

```
WHERE (@Classification != 'NC' and class.Code LIKE @Classification)
  OR (@Classification = 'NC' and class.Code != 'PC')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try modify your query to be:

```
SELECT WhatEverColumnYouNeed  
FROM classification  
WHERE (CASE WHEN class.code IS NULL THEN 'Unclassified'  
            WHEN class.Code = 'PC' THEN 'Compatible'  
            ELSE 'Not-Compatible' END
      ) 
      IN (@Classification)
```

Then make you @Classification a multi-value parameter. Set available value to be Unclassified, Compatible, and Not-Compatible. Values same as Labels.